# Warn about UB in argument evaluation order

Tags: c++, warnings

I recently faced a bug in a code like this

```
class C
{
public:
    // foo return value depends on C's state
    // AND each call to foo changes the state.
    int foo(int arg) /*foo is not const-qualified.*/ {}

private:
    // Some mutable state
};

C c;

bar(c.foo(42), c.foo(43))
```

The last call behaved differently on different platforms (which is perfectly legal due to undefined order of argument evaluation), and I fixed the bug.

But the rest codebase is large and I would like to spot all other UB of this type.

Is there a special compiler warning in GCC, Clang or MSVS for such cases?

And what is the ideomatic and lightweight way to prevent such bugs?

Comment: By lightweight I guess you mean without intermediate variables?

Comment: Intermediate variables are OK. I mean, without currying, for example. `bar(c.foo(42))(c.foo(43))` looks good when called, but requires too much extra code for temporary objects, especially when a ctor is called.

Answer (score 2):

[Argument order evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) is **unspecified** rather than undefined.

> Order of evaluation of the operands of almost all C++ operators (including **the order of evaluation of function arguments in a function-call expression** and the order of evaluation of the subexpressions within any expression) **is unspecified**. The compiler can evaluate operands in any order, and may choose another order when the same expression is evaluated again.

Since it is unspecified rather than undefined behavior, compilers are not required to issue diagnostics for it.

GCC and Clang do not have any general compiler option to issue diagnostics for unspecified behavior.

In GCC there is the option [`fstrong-eval-order`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options) which does this:

> Evaluate member access, array subscripting, and shift expressions in left-to-right order, and evaluate assignment in right-to-left order, as adopted for C++17. Enabled by default with `-std=c++17`. `-fstrong-eval-order=some` enables just the ordering of member access and shift expressions, and is the default without `-std=c++17`.

There is also the option `-Wreorder` (C++ and Objective-C++ only) which does this:

> Warn when the order of member initializers given in the code does not match the order in which they must be executed

But I do not think these options will be helpful in your particular case.

In the below statement, if you want the first argument to be evaluated before the second:

```
bar(c.foo(42), c.foo(43))
```

The simple way is to store the results of `c.foo(42)` and `c.foo(43)` in intermediate variables first and then call `bar()`. (Turn off compiler optimizations to avoid any reordering of statements by the compiler !!)

```
auto var1 = c.foo(42);
auto var2 = c.foo(43);
bar(var1, var2);
```

I guess that is how you must have fixed the bug.

Comment: That's an improvement, but now the post doesn't actually answer the question. The OP didn't ask if the standard required diagnostics; it asked if compilers have switches to *provide* diagnostics in those cases.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Was in the process of editing. Updated now.

Comment: To be honest I'm surprised we don't get warned on this, although I get that it's difficult to detect when such a warning would actually be useful.